# expectation value for minimum distance between random variables

Tags: random-variables, random, expectation

*note: edited to clarify boundary issue*

Suppose $x_i$, $i=1\dots n$, are randomly drawn from a uniform circular distribution between 0 and 1 (using periodic boundaries). Let $d_i$ be the distance between $x_i$ and its nearest neighbour to the right (allowing to wrap at the boundary). Now, the mean for $d_i$ is simply $1/n$. But what is the expectation value for $d_{\min}=\min_i\{d_i\}$? (I reckon it must scale as $E\{d_{\min}\}\propto n^{-2}$ -- correct?)

*update* The distances between uniformly distributed variables are exponentially distributed with rate $n$, i.e. mean $1/n$. Moreover, the minimum of $k$ *independent* exponential variables of rate $\lambda_i$ is also exponentially distributed (see Wikipedia, for example) with rate $\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_k$. So, if the distances were independent, the answer is $E\{d_{\min}\}=1/n^2$. But they aren't independent.

Comment: Walter wrote: "the mean for $d_i$ is simply $1/n$" ........ ---> I think that should be $\frac{1}{1+n}$

Comment: @wolfies **No**, because I have $n$ distances (allowing periodic boundaries) which together give 1.

Comment: You specify $n$ points on a standard Uniform distribution, which in turn defines $n+1$ distances. Why would you then 'assume' periodic boundaries???? If you want periodic boundaries, it might be more appropriate if you adopted a circular distribution.

Comment: @wolfies, *uniform* does not imply non-circular in my mind. Perhaps you're less open-minded? Btw, in a non-periodic setting, there would be $n-1$ distances, not $n+1$ (for $n=2$, there is only one distance). Anyway, this is a mute point irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Yes, it's expected to scale as $n^{-2}$; in fact, it seems that it actually is *equal* to $n^{-2}$. Intuitively, this should be related to definite integral of $(1-nx)^{n-1}$ from $0$ to $1/n$ which considers the set $\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\ |\ \sum x_i=1 \}$ (corresponding to the space of possible distances) as compared to its subset in which we additionally require $(\forall i) x_i\geq x$ (configurations where minimal distance is at least $x$). Of course, intuition might be wrong and needs more rigour -- e.g. are the distances really distributed uniformly (as assumed by the reasoning above)?

Comment: @Walter No - it is not irrelevant to the question, because it changes the solution. Given a standard Uniform distribution, $n$ points define $n+1$ spacings, so $E[d_i]=\frac{1}{n+1}$  (not $1/n$), and $E[d_\text{min}] = \frac{1}{n^2-1}$. A circular Uniform distribution will yield a different result. But the latter seems inconsistent with your definition of distance as $x_i$ and the next largest value.

Comment: @Walter Hmm... this seems to be at odds with a simulation I performed; which seems to match $n^{-2}$ for the $E[d_{min}]$.

Comment: @PeterKošinár You're absolutely correct. There was a bug in my simulation. I fixed it. It's $1/n^2$.

Comment: I agree with @PeterKošinár that the answer seems to be exactly $1/n^2$. While this is not very difficult to prove I'd like to see a reference for it.

Comment: I think the more interesting question is about the expected value of the maximum distance between two neighbouring points. Simulations suggest an exponent of about $0.86$.

Comment: Why would you think that the "distances between uniformly distributed variables are exponentially distributed"? The difference between two uniformly distributions random variables follows a triangle distribution. What is true, however, is that the distribution of a distance, when rescaled by $n$, and the distribution of the minimal distance, rescaled by $n^2$, both converge to an exponential distribution with parameter 1.

Comment: @Eckhard I'm only interested in the limit of large $n$ (I should have said that, sorry).